# Is there a way to write this Query without using the conditions in the brackets?

Tags: mysql, database

> Question: List the name of the cities, the names and continents of
>   their country and the names of all its official languages whose
>   countries lie in the region that starts with 'South'.

Is a question I got from an online exercise system. I couldn't download the data and do not really know what it looks like. 
I am given the following ERD

[image]

```
SELECT 
    city.Name AS 'City Names' , 
    country.Name AS 'Country Names' , 
    country.Continent, 
    countrylanguage.Language
FROM city
INNER JOIN countrylanguage 
    ON (countrylanguage.CountryCode = city.CountryCode AND IsOfficial = true)
INNER JOIN country 
    ON (country.Code = city.CountryCode AND Region = 'South');
```

Once the query launched it gives me in the query log "query returned no results!
"

**Interestingly**, once I take off "AND Region = 'South'" from **my second JOIN** it works out.

Does anyone know what this is the case ? *(I am a beginner)*

Comment: "starts with South"  -->  `AND country.Region LIKE 'South%'`   (the equality comparison  `= 'South'` will only return exact matches  Reference https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like   ... in this sample query, the parens aren't affecting the result ...

Comment: You don't need brackets in an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Without seeing the data in country, it's hard to say. Look at that table to see if it has rows with "South" in it, and if it spelled as such, including case. You could also change `Region = 'South'` to `Region LIKE '%South%'` and see if you get results.

Comment: Spencer's comment fixed it ! Thank you @Obsidian I'll make sure to not make the same mistake